# How to accept model collection metadata, such as count in ember?

Tags: ember-data, ember-cli

In Ember-CLI, how does one go about retrieving/storing model collection metadata?

For example, suppose I have a model 'user' with some defined attributes, and my route retrieves a collection of users with ember-data like so:

```
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findQuery('user', params);
  }
});
```

and the JSON response from my API looks something like this:

```
{ users: [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 2, name: 'Joe'}]}
```

Now, I want to add paging, which means I need a count of total users somewhere in the API response so it looks something like this:

```
{ user_count: 5,
users: [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 2, name: 'Joe'}]}
```

That's simple enough, but how do I access user_count from my Ember controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are in control of the API then you can use built-in support for metadata provided by Ember Data (using `DS.RESTAdapter`).

If you return the following structure from your API:

```
{
  "users": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob"
  }],
  "meta": {
    "user_count": 5
  }
}
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
var meta = this.store.metadataFor("users");
```

and access `meta.user_count`

There is more information in the Ember Guides (v1.10.0): http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/handling-metadata/

If you are not in charge of your API you can use a serializer to format the metadata correctly. Let me know if you need more info on that.

Comment: Wow, I feel a little silly... It was sitting right in the documentation, even citing my pagination use case.

Comment: There's loads going on in Ember! Easy to miss stuff, I do all the time :)

Comment: Could I trouble you to take a look at my other open ember question? Haven't gotten a good answer on it yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010486/how-to-dynamically-apply-classes-to-objects-in-ember-cli