# How to dynamically apply classes to objects in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm creating an app that has a listing of items and a series of filter buttons at the top. As the user applies different filters, I want the buttons to change style using CSS classes to show them as enabled/disabled.

I want to be able to write something like the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
{{#each category in category_options}}
  <button {{action "filterCategory" category}} {{bind-attr class=":btn-small isFiltered(category):btn-active:btn-inactive"}}>{{category}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

In this example, isFiltered is a computed property on the controller, and it looks at the query parameters to determine whether the specified category has been applied as a filter.

From the reading I've done, it sounds like you can't pass parameters to computed properties. I've come across answers mentioning helpers, bound helpers, and components, but I haven't been able to sort out which one I need, or how I would apply it in this situation.

EDIT:
To clarify the example, imagine I have a series of buttons that filter on various tags:

```
Filter for: <Cats> <Dogs> <Rabbits> ... # imagine an arbitrary number of these. dozens, maybe
```

When a user clicks Cats, it triggers filterCategory, which sets the model.category query parameter to ['Cats']. If he then clicks Dogs, model.category becomes ['Cats','Dogs']

Following the latter case, I want the Cats and Dogs buttons to have the class btn-active.

I would like to define isFiltered like so:

```
isFiltered: function(buttonname) {
  if (this.get('model.categories').containsObject(buttonname)) { # pseudocode
    return true;
  }
  else { return false; }
}
```

Passing buttonname into the function makes it easy to do the comparison for every button and determine if it's in the filter.

If this overall approach is the wrong way to go about things, what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)As component you can do something like below:

in template

```
{{#each category in category_options}}
  {{category-button category=category selectedCategoies=selectedCategories action="filterCategory"}}
{{/each}}
```

component template

```
{{category}}
```

component

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  tagName: 'button',
  classNames: 'btn-small',
  classNameBindings: 'isFiltered:btn-active:btn-inactive',

  isFiltered: Ember.computed('category', 'selectedCategories', function(){
    return this.get('selectedCategories').contains(this.get('category'));
  }),
  click: function(){
    this.sendAction('action', this.get('category'));
  }
})
```

2)Or you can make your categories as array of objects like so

```
[
  {name: 'category1', isActive: false},
  {name: 'category2', isActive: true},
  ...
]
```

And then change `isActive` flag as you need.

In controller:

```
categoryObjects: Ember.computed('category_options', function(){
  return this.get('category_options').map(function(category){
    Ember.Object.create({name: category, isActive: false});
  })
}),
actions: {
  filterCategory: function(category){
    category.toggleProperty('isActive');
    return
  }
}
```

And in template:

```
{{#each category in categoryObjects}}
  <button {{action "filterCategory" category}} {{bind-attr class=":btn-small category.isActive:btn-active:btn-inactive"}}>{{category.name}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This feels like it's very close. I'm not familiar with the @get syntax, and node is throwing a syntax error. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have it working (Option #1) by replacing \@get with this.get. Thank you! Would still help if you could explain if @get was a typo or something else I should read up on. You have no idea how frustrating it has been trying to get an answer to this and been roadblocked for a week. This also serves as a nice explanatory example of how components work. I have been close to throwing in the towel on Ember, because it's so hard to find support.

Comment: Oh sorry \@ come from my coffeescript background:) It actually should be this. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the rest of your code looks like but in general you would use `model` hook in your route to get query parameter, process it, if needed, and return with your model, let's say you would return `model.category`, then in your controller you would have something like this:

```
isFiltered: function() {
   var category = this.get('model.category');
   // do whatever you want here with category to return true or false
}.property('model.category')
```

then in `.hbs` you would be able to write this:

```
{{#each category in category_options}}
  <button {{action "filterCategory" category}} {{bind-attr class=":btn-small isFiltered:btn-active:btn-inactive"}}>{{category}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Not sure I'm following. I have, say, 20 categories, which are in the array category_options. In this loop, I want to create 20 buttons, which are each either active or active, depending on whether they are included in the category query parameter. In your code above, isFiltered isn't being called with any parameters, so won't it return the same value for every category button that calls it? I want to add btn-active only for categories that in the query parameter and btn-inactive for all others.

Comment: you can get the value of query param or dynamic segment in the route hooks like `model` for example, from there you would return it so you can use it in your controller like  that `this.get('model.[whatever-object-or-variable-you-return]')`. In the example above `.property('model.category')` is kind of a parameter that you pass in to that property, it would watch it and see if the value changes, if it does it will update` isFiltered`

Comment: or I guess if you deal with query params and not dynamic segments then take a look at this how you can deal with them in your controller http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/query-params/

Comment: Please see my edit, and perhaps that will make my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do this by your approach, you can get it working by making a Computed Property Macro and then looping over the category_options and creating computed properties as isCategory ( isRed, isBlue etc..)

But this won't be the right way to do it, You need to make those button components, which will accept the category_options and model.category and internally decide whether it should be active or not.

Comment: Could you please show some example code for the component and how to call it from the template?